# Select literal in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

I want to construct a SPARQL query populated with values I'm setting as literals.

e.g.

```
SELECT 'A', 'B', attribute
FROM 
    TABLE
```

Would return a table that might look like this:

```
  A    |    B    |    attribute
-------|---------|--------------
  A    |    B    |    Mary
  A    |    B    |    has
  A    |    B    |    a
  A    |    B    |    little
  A    |    B    |    lamb
```

What I want to do is run a query like this to get all the object types in a triplestore:

```
select distinct ?o ("class" as ?item_type) 
where {
    ?s rdf:type ?o.
}
```

and then (ideally) UNION it with a second query that pulls out all the distinct predicate values:

```
select distinct ?p ("predicate" as ?item_type) 
where {
    ?s ?p ?o.
}
```

the results of which might look like:

```
  item           |    item_type    
-----------------|-----------------
 a_thing         |    class
another_thing    |    class
a_relation       |    predicate
another_relation |    predicate
```

But a UNION in SPARQL only links in an additional where clause, which means I can't specify the item_type literal I want to inject into my results-set.

Comment: Do you mean `("object" as ?subject)`?  Which is still a rather odd way of saying it.  Maybe you want to say `("class" as ?item_type)` and `("predicate" as ?item_type)`?

Comment: Yes, that's a cleaner way of putting it. I'll amend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following should get you what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?item_type
WHERE {
   { ?s a ?item .
     BIND("class" AS ?item_type)
   }
   UNION
   { ?s ?item ?o
     BIND("predicate" AS ?item_type)
   }
```

}

Comment: Ahhh,so *that*'s what bind does - ok excellent - thankyou very much for that :)